# set height in relation to width

Tags: javascript, iframe, responsive-design

How do I set the height of an iframe by it's width?

```
<iframe width="100%" height="auto" id="youtube" ... >

window.onresize function() {
    document.getElementById("youtube").style.height = this.style.width*0.63;
}
```

I'd like to use only javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't using window.onresize quite right by missing the equals sign to declare the function...

```
<iframe width="100%" height="auto" id="youtube" ... >
window.onresize = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("youtube").style.height = document.getElementById("youtube").style.width*0.63;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interval that run in the background and updates the frame to match.

```
function autoAdjustWidth(){
    var frm=document.getElementById('myFrame');
    console.log(frm.offsetWidth);
    frm.height=frm.offsetWidth;
}
autoAdjustWidth();
window.setInterval(autoAdjustWidth,300);
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXUjf/).

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks almost correct with a few changes:

```
 // using =
 window.onresize = function() {
    var iFrame =  document.getElementById("youtube");
    // use iFrame width instead of "this" which is the windows width
    iFrame.style.height = iFrame.style.width;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var player = null;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    resizeHeroVideo();
} );

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeHeroVideo();
});

function resizeHeroVideo() {
    var content = $('#hero');
    var contentH = viewportSize.getHeight();
    contentH -= 158;
    content.css('height',contentH);

    if(player != null) {
        var iframe = $('.videoWrapper iframe');
        var iframeH = contentH - 150;
        if (isMobile) {
            iframeH = 163; 
        }
        iframe.css('height',iframeH);
        var iframeW = iframeH/9 * 16;
        iframe.css('width',iframeW);
    }
}
```

[Complete gist here.](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/647fcdda17cd23715872)  [Live example here.](https://www.thebouqs.com/en/content/8-how-it-works)